# How to move the cursor outside of a span element after inserting it?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I've created a custom plugin that lets me insert icons from an icon font inside my document. I have it set up so that it creates a span element with the icon of my choice inside of it.

It does work, but once I insert the icon, the cursor is inside the span element, which causes issues if I immediately try typing afterwards. I can just clear formatting, but it is a bit annoying, so I'd like to know if I can tell my plugin to automatically shift the cursor outside of the span I've just inserted so that I can continue to type freely. It'd be great if I could also "lock" the span so that I can't click inside of it by accident.

Here's what my code looks like:

```js
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'iconDialog', function ( editor ) {
    return {
        title: 'Add icon',
        minWidth: 400,
        minHeight: 200,

        contents: [
            {
                id: 'tab',
                label: 'Add a new icon',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'iconId',
                        label: 'Paste the icon here',
                        validate: CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.notEmpty( "Icon name can't be empty." )
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        onOk: function() {
            var dialog = this;
            var id = dialog.getValueOf('tab', 'iconId');
            editor.insertHtml( '<span class="inv-icon">' + id.toString() + '</span>' );
        }
    };
});
```